# Why is my CollectionViewSource/ICollectionView leaking memory?

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

My application (c# wpf) has a listbox bound to a collection of ViewModels that is to display these VMs as individual UserControls.  Last night I attempted to implementing a filter by creating an ICollectionView from a CollectionViewSource and though the filtering works, it is leaking memory.  It seems every time I run the filter it is creating an additional collection and not disposing of it.

I don't really know what I'm doing and I'm mostly learning on the fly.  I haven't used a CollectionViewSource in this manner before so I'm not familiar.

The Process:

Step 1: Populate List JobTileVMs

Step 2: CreateJobFilter()

```
private void CreateJobFilter(Task obj)
    {
        View = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(JobTileVMs);
        View.Filter = null;

    }
```

Step 3: My ListBox is bound to View

```
private ICollectionView view;
    public ICollectionView View
    {
        get { return view; }
        set
        {
            Set(ref view, value);
        }
    }
```

Step 4: Upon user button click, run filter

```
private void FilterCustomerJobs()
    {
        View.Filter = item =>
        {
            JobTileVM vm = item as JobTileVM;
            if (vm.Jobs[0].Customer.StartsWith("SomeCustomer")) return true;
            return false;
        };
    }
private void FilterCustomerJobs2()
    {
        View.Filter = item =>
        {
            JobTileVM vm = item as JobTileVM;
            if (vm.Jobs[0].Customer.StartsWith("SomeOtherCustomer")) return true;
            return false;
        };
    }
```

So where I'm at right now, the filtering does successfully filter the displayed list but my memory will keep growing if I toggle back and forth between my two filter functions.

I tried digging around for a bit and didn't come up with much, but I did notice that my view property had a parameter UseLocalArray as true, or something with a similar name.

So, what am I doing wrong and how should I be doing it?

Comment: Is the CollectionView subscribing to any events? It looks like you are setting the collection view to another object. If the object it was set to before has subscribed to any events, it will still be referenced and therefore overlooked during GC.

Comment: Are PropertyChanged stuff events (I'm new!)?  JobTileVMs has an accessor that implements a property changed notification.  I just tried setting my CollectionViewSource to the private list (_jobTileVMs) and this did not change anything.  I've pretty much posted all of the code involving my CollectionView stuff.  I don't have any events active in code-behind either.